# How to host substrate-node-template on gcp using Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have been trying to deploy our substrate-node-template on gcp as a docker container. To do that I need to write a Dockerfile, since the node runs on 9944 port I couldn't figure out on deploying this on gcp.
I have come this far with my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rustlang/rust:nightly

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install -y cmake pkg-config libssl-dev git gcc build-essential clang libclang-dev

RUN rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release


ENV environment dev
ENV place ws-external


CMD ["sh", "-c", "/app/target/release/node-template --${environment} --${place}"]

EXPOSE 9944
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful if you could provide details on how you deployed and what  your problem exactly is.

My 2 cents would be to first try running your image locally using docker and check if you run into the same issue.

Please note that using `EXPOSE 9944` does **not** actually expose port `9944` but only document that your node should serve something on port `9944`.

The command to test your image will then have to look like:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9966:944 <your_image>
```

This would make your node reachable locally on port `9966` (I used another port than `9944` to point out that you do not **have** to use the same port number.

This however **still** will not be enough since your node is inside a Docker image and will only listen to request from within the Docker image (which is rather useless...) and likely filter the rpc requests you are interested in.

You should look at the [Polkadot Dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/polkadot/polkadot_builder.Dockerfile) for inspiration and check out the [documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/doc/docker.md) to see how to start your container.